# Estou a ter um problema ao carregar uma imagem com Multer no servidor, o ficheiro carrega para a 'path' mas não para a base de dados

Tags: node.js, express.js, multer

Na minha máquina funciona perfeitamente, a imagem é carregada para a path e todos os dados para a base de dados mas no servidor ubuntu com o mesmo código e a mesma base de dados apenas a imagem é carregada para a path e nenhum dos dados é carregado para a db.

```js
const path = require('path')
const multer  = require('multer')

const uploadImg = function (req, res) {
    
  let file_name = ''
  var values = [];

  const storage = multer.diskStorage({

      destination: path.join(__dirname, '../../public/imgcomment/'),
      filename: function(req, file, cb){
        const uni = new Date().getTime();
        file_name = uni + '-' + file.originalname
        cb(null, uni + '-' + file.originalname);
      }

  });

  const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
      checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
  }).single('images');


// Check File Type
  function checkFileType(file, cb){

    // Allowed ext
    const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
    // Check ext
    const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
    // Check mime
    const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);
  
    if(mimetype && extname){
      return cb(null,true);
    } else {
      cb('Error: Images Only!');
    }

  }

  

  upload(req, res, (err) => {

    const nome = req.body.nome;
    const descricao = req.body.descricao;
    const preco = req.body.preco;
    const category = req.body.category;

      if(err){

        console.log(err)

      } else {

        if(req.file == undefined){

          console.log('Error: No File Selected!')

        } else {

          values.push([nome, descricao, preco, file_name, category]);
          console.log(values)

          db.query('INSERT INTO produtos (nome, descricao, preco, images, categoria) VALUES ?', [values], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              error = 'SQL ERROR ' + err.sqlMessage;
            }
            else {
              error = 'Blog added successfully';
            }
            req.flash('success', error);
            res.redirect('/todolist');
          });
          
        }
      }
    })
}

module.exports = {
    uploadImg: uploadImg
}
```

Alguém sabe o que pode causar este problema? muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente é porque você precisa dos dados e do arquivo ao mesmo tempo e no server o parsing pode demorar um pouco. Experimente usar o método any ao invés do single no multer.